# Constructing a single qubit gate from S, H and Pauli gates

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, linear-algebra

How can we construct a single qubit gate $U = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{4}}*\exp(−\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{4} Y)$ from $S$, $H$ (Hadamard), and Pauli gates?

I already know that final answer will be:

$$SHSHS3 = SHSHS^\dagger$$

I just don't know the process that led to this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a simpler way of doing this, but this certainly works.

First find the matrix representation of $U$ by multiplying out the terms. Remember that $e^{i \theta Y} = \cos(\theta) I + i \sin(\theta)Y$. The final result (thank you Sympy) is

$$
U = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
1 + i & -1 - i  \\
 1 + i & 1 + i  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now all single qubit transforms can be translated mechanically into the form $e^{i\gamma} R_Z(\phi) R_X(\theta)R_Z(\lambda)$.  Qiskit provides a method to do that:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import OneQubitEulerDecomposer

decomposer = OneQubitEulerDecomposer('ZXZ')
phi, theta, lam, gamma = decomposer.angles_and_phase(U)
```

You learn that $\theta = \phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\lambda = \frac{-\pi}{2}$, and $\gamma = \frac{\pi}4$.

Now $R_Z(\phi) = R_Z(\pi/2)$ is just $S$, and $R_Z(\lambda) = R_Z(-\pi/2)$ is just $S^\dagger$.  Any rotation around the X axis can be expressed as a rotation around the Z axis preceded and followed by an `H`.  So $R_X(\theta) = H R_Z(\theta) H = H S H$

We have a leftover global phase $\gamma$ which we can ignore.

Putting the pieces together you get $S HSH SSS$.

Answer (score 4):

I go about this in quite a different way (and get a different result). You're trying to make
$$
e^{-i\pi Y/4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(I-iY).
$$
Start by considering Hadamard:
$$
H=\frac{X+Z}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
We can use Pauli relations to write $Z=-iXY$. Hence,
$$
H=X\frac{I-iY}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
Thus, $e^{i\pi Y/4}=XH$. This is exactly what you want up to a global phase (and global phases don't matter).